Finding the longest snake on a grid
I'm trying to solve some variants of the following problem:

A 2D rectangular grid is given. Find the longest "snake" on it. Informally, a snake is a path that does not touch itself. In graph theory terms, it is a path without chords, or equivalently, an induced subgraph that is a path.

For OEIS A331968, the width and height are equal, but there are no further constraints. For IOI 2010 Problem 7 "Maze", the path of length $N$ must consist of 1 border cell (the entrance) and $N-1$ interior cells, and it cannot pass through obstacles.
For example, input file 9 looks like this
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########
#####################
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########
##########X##########

and a solution of length 106 (optimal) is
####.#####X##########
###..#....X#....#...#
##..#..##.X..##...#.#
#..#..#...X.#..####.#
#.#..#..##X.#.#...#.#
#...##.#....#.#.#...#
####...#.#X#..#..####
#....###..X..###....#
#.###...#.X.#...###.#
#.....#...X...#.....#
##########X##########

Large inputs for Maze are of size 100x100 (inputs 2 ~ 5) and 200x200 (input 10). I tried several MIP models for a path on a graph, but free MIP solvers such as CBC or SCIP could not handle 100x100 tests (they either choked on memory or barely made any progress after 10+ hours). I settled with CP-SAT with its circuit built-in constraint, which managed to find a path of length 4000+ within an hour and 4250+ in six hours for input 2. However, it is still struggling for other large inputs.
The MIP model was the following:

Define a grid graph over the given grid of $R$ rows and $C$ columns. Let $V_{rc}$ be the node at row $r$ and column $c$, and $E_{rcr'c'}$ be the edge from $V_{rc}$ to $V_{r'c'}$. $1 \le r, r' \le R$, $1 \le c, c' \le C$, $E_{rcr'c'}$ exists iff $|r-r'| + |c-c'| = 1$.
Add two dummy nodes $S$ for the start of the path, and $E$ for the end. Add edges $E_{Src}$ from $S$ to border nodes $V_{rc}$, and $E_{rcE}$ from interior nodes $V_{rc}$ to $E$.
Binary variables $v_{rc}$ indicate if $V_{rc}$ is part of the path. Binary variables $e_{x}$ indicate if $E_{x}$ is part of the path.
Maximize the number of nodes in the path. $$\max \sum_{rc} v_{rc}$$
In order to form a path, at each node $V_{rc}$, the number of used incoming edges must be equal to that of used outgoing edges. Also, $V_{rc}$ is part of the path iff there are exactly one incoming edge and exactly one outgoing edge. $$\forall r \forall c, \sum_{x} e_{xrc} = \sum_{y} e_{rcy} = v_{rc}$$
In order to ensure a "snake", for two adjacent nodes $V_x$ and $V_y$, $e_{xy} = e_{yx} = 0$ iff $v_x + v_y \le 1$, and $e_{xy} + e_{yx} = 1$ iff $v_x = v_y = 1$. This is encoded as $$\forall x \forall y \text{ s.t. } E_{xy} \text{ exists}, v_x + v_y - 1 \le 2(e_{xy} + e_{yx}) \le  v_x + v_y$$
In order to eliminate subtours, introduce another integer (or real) variable per node $u_{rc}$ with domain $[0, rc-1]$ and $$\forall x \forall y \text{ s.t. } E_{xy} \text{ exists}, u_x - u_y + 1 \le rc(1 - e_{xy})$$
Ensure that only one border cell is used. $$\sum_{r=1 \vee r=R \vee c=1 \vee c=C} v_{rc} = 1$$
Ensure that obstacle cells are not used. $$\forall r \forall c, \text{grid}[r][c] = \text{X} \Rightarrow v_{rc} = 0$$

The current CP-SAT model works as follows:

Remove one layer from all four sides of the input.
Create a node for each of the remaining cells, and one dummy node to start and end the path.
For each outermost cell, if it can "escape" through a directly adjacent cell, add a directed edge from dummy to that cell.
For example, if the input file looked like
XXXX#
XABC#
###D#
#####
#####

then C and D would be connected, but A and B would not.
Since any interior cell can be the end of the path, add directed edges from all of them to dummy.
Connect every pair of orthogonally adjacent cells in both directions.
Add self loops to specify that they can be out of the path.
Add the circuit constraint with this graph.
For each pair of orthogonally adjacent cells, add a logical constraint that, if both X and Y are in the path (this is specified using boolean negation of self loop edges), one of the edges X -> Y and Y -> X is in the path. This is done with the code
model.AddBoolOr(edge1, edge2).OnlyEnforceIf([node1, node2])


Specify that the X cells are not used. (The code reduces the number of variables by using constant 0 or 1 wherever appropriate.)
Maximize the sum of boolean variables indicating that a node is used, plus 1 (the border cell).

The questions:

Is there any better modeling and/or tool for this problem?
I'm guessing that longer paths can be found more easily if the search prioritizes those with many 90-degree turns. However, adding such terms to the objective seems to degrade the search. Is it possible to achieve this effect in CP-SAT (or any other free solver)?
The input file 3 is not "solved" by anyone (condition: find a path of length 4000) at the moment. Running my model on this input for 12 hours, CP-SAT reports that the upper bound of the objective is 3994, which is less than 4000. Can anyone else confirm that a path of length 4000 does not exist?


A few questions:

For the problem you exemplified, $N = 106$, right?
"I tried several MIP models for a path on a graph", could you please elaborate more on this? Maybe write down the variables, constraints, ... (if you could use the literature notation, as here wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Proof_of_NP-hardness, it would be better to read)? Because, there are several MIP solving techniques for enhancing performance, such as: branch and cut, column generation, preprocessing, so on...


@MatheusDiógenesAndrade 1) Yes. 2) I'll try. In short, circuit is replaced with a graph path formulation with global subcircuit elimination using an integer variable per node. I also tried dynamically adding cycle cut constraints, but it was taking forever to cut every possible cycle even in 20x20 inputs.

Thanks. That is awesome. Well, it would be interesting to come to formal and detailed terms the tentatives you have made so far, because, sometimes, there are a lot of empty spaces to explore, without the need to change the framework, be it MILP, or Constraint Programming.

Meanwhile, I did some more research and found this paper on the OEIS page. It suggests that filling open spaces with adjacent staircases (which uses 2/3 of the whole space asymptotically) is likely near optimal. Now the question is if it is possible to incorporate this information in CP-SAT or MIP.

Thanks for the effort, and I am sorry for taking so much time for answering your question.

You might be interested in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.07012

Hey @Bubbler! I just found this question. If you need help with SCIP/PySCIPOpt, don't be afraid to open an Issue or a discussion over on the repo, we'd be happy to try and help! :) We're in talks of merging PyGCGOpt into PySCIPOpt, but we haven't come to a decision and might take some time.

For your question 3, I derived an upper bound of $3988$, obtained via a relaxation that has only node-based binary decision variables and does not enforce connectivity.


Out of curiosity, which (MI)LP solver do you use for puzzle-like problems?

I use SAS: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_055/casmopt/titlepage.htm?fromDefault=

I've been tinkering with this problem for quite a while, and I'd like to share my progress so far.
Relevant papers:

[1]: Bokler et al., An Experimental Study of ILP Formulations for the Longest Induced Path Problem

This one was suggested by @RobPratt. Suggests a formulation named $ILP_{cut}$.


[2]: Marzo et al., New formulations and branch-and-cut procedures
for the longest induced path problem

This one was published after Bokler's. Suggests two formulations named $cec$ and $cut$, and seems to be empirically better than $ILP_{cut}$.


[3]: Anaqreh et al., Exact Methods for the Longest Induced Cycle Problem

This one solves a closely related problem using existing formulations, including $ILP_{cut}$ and $cec$. Also suggests a method called "tough cut generation" which actively adds a constraint specifying (objective value) >= (best found path) + 1 as part of the cut generation process.


[4]: Nikolai Beluhov, Snake Paths in King and Knight Graphs

This is not an MIP formulation, but shows the theoretical lower and upper bounds of the length of the longest snake on rectangular grid graphs.



Trying various modelings
The IOI instances are way too large at the moment, so I decided to focus on the OEIS version of the problem.
I coded $ILP_{cut}$ and $cec$, and integral and fractional cuts for both of them, in PySCIPOpt. Some implementation details:

For the integral cut of $ILP_{cut}$, finding cycles was straightforward, but finding good cuts out of them seems to be a hard problem. I tried cutting the cycle and cutting small enclosed areas together. I also tried adding $k$ cuts or $1$ cut on a cycle of length $k$.
The fractional cut of $ILP_{cut}$ is straightforward: compute the flow from every vertex to the end. While there are extremely fast flow algorithms, computing it $|V|$ times is very expensive, and cannot be as fast as the fractional cycle cut algorithm for $cec$ (described below).
For the fractional cut of $cec$, instead of guessing what the authors did, I invented a new one. Given the values $y_v$ assigned to each vertex, assign edge weights $x_{uv} = \frac{y_u + y_v}{2}$ and compute the maximum spanning tree. For each edge not in the tree, identify the cycle formed by adding it, and check if it is too large. If so, add a constraint cutting it. The sum of edge weights in a cycle computed this way equals the sum of vertex weights. This algorithm can test $|E| - |V| + 1$ cycles in $\mathcal{O}((|V| + |E|) \log(|V| + |E|))$ time.
3-cliques do not exist in grid graphs, so I didn't code clique cut constraints at all. Instead, some small cycles are readily visible, so I tested pre-adding cut constraints for 4- (size 1x1) and 8-cycles (size 2x2).

I haven't recorded precise timings, but here are some general results so far:

Whatever cut method I used for $ILP_{cut}$, it converged slower than $cec$. This roughly matches the findings in [3].
I think I coded "tough cut generation" in [3] correctly, but it didn't meaningfully change the running time to optimality.
Barrier method seems to be faster than simplex. LP solutions were enough to find the optimal solutions for various sizes, so I turned off most primal heuristics.
Pre-adding small cycle cuts tended to negatively impact the performance. Only a small fraction of such cycles seem to be used in the end.

At this point, $14 \times 14$ was solved to optimality in 5 hours.
Finding and supplying initial solution(s)
[4] provides a constructive solution that serves as a lower bound. The solution is found by painting the grid with a repeating staircase pattern that fills $\frac{2}{3}$ of the entire space and then fixing the boundaries to form a single zigzag snake. Visually it looks like
..#..#..#      ..#...###
.#..#..#.      .#..#.###
#..#..#..      ...#..###
..#..#..#      ###..#...
.#..#..#.  =>  ##..#..#.
#..#..#..      #..#..#..
..#..#..#      ..#..#..#
.#..#..#.      .#..##.#.
#..#..#..      ...###...

But it is tedious to apply such fixes manually, so I came up with a hack: solve some MIP instances with many variables fixed. More precisely, I solve the same instance but with the inner region pre-filled with the staircase pattern, leaving out 2 outer layers to be solved. Three such instances can be formed (excluding cells where (r+c)%3 is 0, 1, or 2 respectively), and I add all three optimal solutions as the initial solution for the main problem. Most of them were solved in a second for the sizes I tested with.
This method finds solutions that are extremely close to the optimal of the main problem, and the running time for $14 \times 14$ was reduced to 3 hours. $16 \times 16$ was also solved to optimality in 21 hours. I kept $18 \times 18$ running, and the solver was able to find $205 \le a_{18} \le 208$ after 72 hours.
Results
Initial (staircase heuristic) and final optimal solution values




10
11
12
13
14




10
63 / 64
70 / 71
75 / 77
82 / 84
87 / 89


11

76 / 77
84 / 86
89 / 92
97 / 98


12


90 / 92
98 / 100
105 / 107


13



105 / 107
114 / 115


14




122 / 123



Simplex performance
For the next two tables, "nodes" and "depth" are the values marked "(total)", which counts all runs if a restart occurred. Both initial and final bound gaps were computed with respect to the final optimal solution.




10
11
12
13
14




10
time: 18snodes: 1685depth: 12 initial bound: 70.987 (10.92%) final bound: 68.906 (7.67%)
time: 22snodes: 1591depth: 18 initial bound: 77.706 (9.44%) final bound: 75.732 (6.67%)
time: 41snodes: 1976depth: 20 initial bound: 84.615 (9.89%) final bound: 82.255 (6.83%)
time: 56snodes: 1856depth: 16 initial bound: 91.370 (8.77%) final bound: 89.438 (6.47%)
time: 292s nodes: 6379depth: 24 initial bound: 98.289 (10.44%) final bound: 94.234 (5.88%)


11

time: 135s nodes: 3615depth: 20 initial bound: 85.373 (10.87%) final bound: 83.240 (8.10%)
time: 28s nodes: 1143depth: 19 initial bound: 92.668 (7.75%) final bound: 90.632 (5.39%)
time: 100s nodes: 2652depth: 22 initial bound: 100.28 (9.00%) final bound: 97.923 (6.44%)
time: 365s nodes: 9201depth: 24 initial bound: 107.89 (10.09%) final bound: 103.98 (6.10%)


12


time: 221s nodes: 5340depth: 26 initial bound: 100.96 (9.74%) final bound: 98.837 (7.43%)
time: 321s nodes: 5590depth: 25 initial bound: 109.02 (9.02%) final bound: 104.98 (4.98%)
time: 581s nodes: 12641depth: 25 initial bound: 117.28 (9.61%) final bound: 113.29 (5.88%)


13



time: 1279s nodes: 31158depth: 27 initial bound: 118.02 (10.30%) final bound: 113.94 (6.48%)
time: 2597s nodes: 157880depth: 30 initial bound: 126.87 (10.32%) final bound: 122.81 (6.80%)


14




time: 10081s nodes: 696615depth: 33 initial bound: 136.51 (10.98%) final bound: 131.28 (6.74%)



Barrier performance




10
11
12
13
14




10
time: 12snodes: 2094depth: 28 initial bound: 70.987 (10.92%) final bound: 69.218 (8.15%)
time: 11snodes: 1563depth: 17 initial bound: 77.706 (9.44%) final bound: 75.897 (6.90%)
time: 35snodes: 3762depth: 23 initial bound: 84.615 (9.89%) final bound: 82.507 (7.15%)
time: 19snodes: 1864depth: 20 initial bound: 91.370 (8.77%) final bound: 89.449 (6.49%)
time: 91s nodes: 6154depth: 25 initial bound: 98.289 (10.44%) final bound: 94.257 (5.91%)


11

time: 43s nodes: 3703depth: 19 initial bound: 85.373 (10.87%) final bound: 77.0 (0.00%)
time: 12s nodes: 1665depth: 20 initial bound: 92.668 (7.75%) final bound: 90.913 (5.71%)
time: 47s nodes: 3655depth: 25 initial bound: 100.28 (9.00%) final bound: 96.174 (4.54%)
time: 127s nodes: 7137depth: 23 initial bound: 107.89 (10.09%) final bound: 103.98 (6.10%)


12


time: 76s nodes: 4553depth: 26 initial bound: 100.96 (9.74%) final bound: 97.616 (6.10%)
time: 79s nodes: 4270depth: 24 initial bound: 109.02 (9.02%) final bound: 105.10 (5.10%)
time: 265s nodes: 15043depth: 35 initial bound: 117.28 (9.61%) final bound: 113.45 (6.03%)


13



time: 469s nodes: 26966depth: 31 initial bound: 118.02 (10.30%) final bound: 114.15 (6.68%)
time: 1015s nodes: 54847depth: 33 initial bound: 126.87 (10.32%) final bound: 115.0 (0.00%)


14




time: 9775s nodes: 557710depth: 33 initial bound: 136.51 (10.98%) final bound: 131.48 (6.90%)



Next steps
I'm considering applying parallelism and/or Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition, both of which are available as part of SCIP suite (UG and GCG respectively). UG seems not yet stable, so I think I'll try applying GCG with PyGCGOpt. One open question though is whether it can handle lazy constraints as in PySCIPOpt.

Congratulations for the effort and thanks for updating us. Well, for a more precise recommendation, would be interesting to have more info about: ($i$) the number of BB nodes; ($ii$) and the largest depth of the BB tree of a "good debugging" instance; ($iii$) the execution time of the Barrier and the Simplex; And ($iv$) the initial GAP (GAP at the root node) before and after adding the selected cuts. Btw, the DW decomposition also would be my next bet.

@MatheusDiógenesAndrade I updated the post with some experimental results.

Thanks for the effort, and sorry for the delay. Interesting resuts. So, if it is not asking too much, could you also report the number of founded: ($i$) integral cuts of $ILP_{cut}$; ($ii$) fractional cuts of $ILP_{cut}$; And, ($iii$) fractional cut of $cec$? Btw, concerning the fractional cuts of $ILP_{cut}$, some authors apply these cuts only at the root node (of the BB tree), due to the, as you pointed out, the complexity for calculating them. Also, if you want to go further on valid inequalities, you may check section 3 of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2023.07.034.

Thanks for the effort in deeply describing the problem. Firstly, I will re-describe the problem under a similiar notation, and then I will present some alternatives for tackling the problem.
Grid
Let

$R = \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant n}$ and $C = \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant m}$ be the set of rows and columns, respectively;
$P \subset R \times C$ be the set of prohibited cells;
$F = (R \times C) \backslash P$ be the set of "feasible" cells;
$B = \{ (r,c) \in F : r \in \{1, m\} \vee c \in \{1, n \} \}$ be the set of "feasible" border cells; And
$A(r, c) = \{ (r, c) \in F : |r - r^{'}| + |c - c^{'}| = 1 \}$ be the set of "feasible" neighbors of cell $(r, c)$.

Grid graph
Let $G(V, E)$ be the resulting undirected unweighted grid-graph, where:

$V = \{s, t\} \cup \{ v_{rc} : (r,c) \in F \}$, such that $s$ and $t$ are source and terminal nodes, respectively;
$E = \{ st \} \cup \{ sv_{rc} : (r,c) \in B \} \cup \{ tv_{rc} : (r,c) \in F \backslash B \} \cup$ $\{ v_{rc}v_{r^{'}c^{'}} : (r,c) \in F \wedge (r^{'}, c^{'}) \in A(r, c) \}$ (note that, here, the edge direction does not matter); And
$V_B = \{ v_{rc} : (r, c) \in B \}$ is the set of "feasible" border nodes.

OP
The aforementioned problem, is strongly related to the Orienteering Problem (OP). Here, I will propose a MILP formulation for an OP-variant designed to our problem. For more infor about OP, cf. here.

$\sum_{i \in V} z_i = N + 2$ (path length constraint);
$x_{st} = z_s = z_t = 1$ (source and target degree constraint);
$\sum_{e \in \delta(i)} x_e = 2 z_i$, $\forall i \in V$ (dedgree/continuity constraint);
$x_{ij} \geqslant z_j + z_i - 1$, $\forall ij \in E$ (chords elimination constraint);
$\sum_{i \in V_B} z_i = 1$ (single border cell constraint);
$\sum_{e \in \delta(S)} x_e \geqslant 2 (z_i + z_j - 1)$, $\forall S \subset V \backslash \{s, t\}, i \in S, j \in V \backslash S$ (subtour elimination constraint); And
$x \in \mathbb{B}^{|E|}, z \in \mathbb{B}^{|V|}$ (domain constraints).

The separation of constraint 5 (cf. Section 4.2.1. of this paper for more info) have to be made by means of Lazy-Callbacks, and can be also explored by means of User-Cut-Callbacks (for both types of callbacks, cf. here).
The paper also provides more classes of cuts for strengthening purposes, although some of them use the length limit parameter $T$, you could take $T$ as an upper bound for the nodes number of the optimal path (for now, I am not sure how to obtain it, maybe later I will come up with something).
Another improvement may be taken, is to explore the properties associated with the grid-graph structure, here you can find something related.
Furthermore, given the dimensions of the instances you aim to solve, maybe a Cut & Pricing (C&P) or even a Branch & Cut & Price (B&C&P) scheme may be required (cf. here).
Note that, so far, I am presenting several strategies that require to go deep into the use of an MILP solver, i.e. it is not anymore a question simply delegating the solving to a tool and use it as a black-box, maybe for the LP part only.
Concerning the use of Constraint Programming (CP), it is interesting to bear in mind that one of the advantages of MILP over CP, is that the underlying LP part of an MILP solver allows better prunings during the derivation tree. However, this does not mean that MILP > CP, it may happen the opposite, that is, experimentation will be necessary.
Another path you may find interesting, is to explore Dynamic Programming (DP) methods, for such, you could check the literature on Decision Diagrams.
UPDATE 1: I noticed that the desired path length $N$ is given as input, therefore, I removed the objective function and replaced it in form of a constraint (constraint 0). Also, I changed the function $N(i)$ to $A(i)$ to avoid misunderstanding.

I do not know what is your aim, if you are doing this for research, competition, or simply fun, purposes. But, if you are interested in diving into the B&C, C&P, B&C&P, and DP part (or even another unfathoned algorithm), we can extend this thread as much as you want.

I'm mainly doing this for fun. Thank you for so many references to look into. I just found out that PySCIPOpt has a tutorial that shows almost exactly what we need here (lazy subtour elimination), so I guess I'll give SCIP another chance.

Here is the code in ortools
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-large-your-snake-cp-approach-alireza-soroudi-phd-36vbe
git repository: https://github.com/OptimizationExpert/Pyomo/blob/main/Snake_CP.ipynb


Could you display the objective function value ?
